# If there is Negative Value anther column should get Text

Tags: excel, vba

How to get Negative as a comment in cell of column B corresponding to cell in column A, when values in the cells of column A is negative.

for example:

```
   A     B
   12
 -123   Negative
  123
 -456   Negative
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution 1

Using VBA

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cel As range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")                  'change Sheet2 to your data sheet
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'get last row with data
        For Each cel In range("A1:A" & lastRow)             'loop through Column A
            If cel.Value < 0 Then cel.Offset(0, 1) = "Negative" 'check if number is negative
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

#### Solution 2

Using Formula

Enter the following formula in `Cell B1` then drag/copy down as required.

```
=IF(SIGN(A1)=-1,"Negative","")
```

[image]